# How to sync litecoin blockchain (+ bootstrap) from the terminal?

Tags: blockchain, litecoin, synchronization, bootstrap.dat

I've installed Litecoin from the main page, so now I have few executable files, like `litecoin-cli`, `litecoind`, `litecion-qt`, ...

I know, that the easiest way to sync blockchain is to run `./litecoin-qt` and it will start the syncing automaticly. More than that, I've downloaded [bootstrap.dat](https://litecoin.info/Bootstrap.dat), so know the stuff will get synced much faster.

But how can I do it, without QT GUI, only using the terminal?

Comment: Run `./litecoind`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it really works the same way as a Bitcoin: just run `./liteciond -daemon` and syncing will start automatically.

Answer (score 0):

litecoind will sync the blockchain the same way as litecoin-qt, and you can interact with it via RPC calls or with litecoin-cli, both from terminal. Also, bootstrap is not recommended generally for newer bitcoin codebases.

Answer (score 0):

The same way, put the bootstrap file in the datafolder (~/.litecoin on linux) and run litecoind ./litecoind